# Access denied for user 'database username'@'%' to database 'information_schema'

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using 000webhost for creating database.

The error is,
**Error: Access denied for user '(database username)'@'%' to database 'information_schema'**

i am getting error in register.php file,i am attaching my register.php code here

```
<?php
require 'init.php';
$name=$_POST["name"];
$city=$_POST["city"];
$blood_group=$_POST["blood_group"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$number=$_POST["number"];


$sql="INSERT INTO uuser_table (name,city,blood_group,password,number) VALUES ('$name','$city','$blood_group','$password','$number')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($result){
    echo "Success";
}
else{
    echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($con);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

here init.php file works fine.while including the register.php file the error occurs.
It showed access denied to database 'information_schema'.the information_schema is default and i haven't changed anything.

[In the myphpadmin database name,information_schema . Mysql is absent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiPxV.png)

please help me solving his access issue. Thanks:)

Comment: What's inside init.php?

Comment: <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="database user";
    $pass="password";
    $db="database name";
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    if($con){
        echo "Connected to Database";
    }
    else{
        echo "Failed to connect ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>

Comment: This is my init.php file check our this.!

Comment: what is the output of `show grants for 'database username'@'%';` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql: access denied on information\_schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989356/mysql-access-denied-on-information-schema)